# How to set TextView Dynamically left of paraent?

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

here is my code i got error params is null

```
     viewDynamic = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
     RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)viewDynamic.getLayoutParams();
     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,userEditTxt.getId());


     viewDynamic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     viewDynamic.setText(userEditTxt.getText());
     viewDynamic.setTextColor(Color.RED);
     viewDynamic.setTextScaleX(2);
     viewDynamic.setTextSize(20);
     viewDynamic.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
   //viewDynamic.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     relativeLayout.addView(viewDynamic,params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't added the view to any parent container, or havent called setLayoutParams manually, then getLayoutParams() will return null.

Make soure you call `viewDynamic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` **before** you call `viewDynamic.getLayoutParams();`, or add the view to a container, so LayoutParams will be generated for the view.

I suggest you add your View like this:

```
 viewDynamic = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,userEditTxt.getId());

 viewDynamic.setText(userEditTxt.getText());
 viewDynamic.setTextColor(Color.RED);
 viewDynamic.setTextScaleX(2);
 viewDynamic.setTextSize(20);
 viewDynamic.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

 relativeLayout.addView(viewDynamic,params);//you attach params to your View here
```

Comment: If it did, please consider accepting my vote as the answer, just left to my answer.